# Excel If 2 cells match third returns specific text

Tags: excel

This seems like a simple request but I am struggling to find a simple answer. 
I have 3 cells, let’s call them A1, B1, C1. I would like a formula to address the following:
If the numerical values in A1 and B1 match then C1 needs to show the text “complete”
If the numbers in A1 and B1 do not match then C1 to show text “Partial”
If there is nothing in A1 and B1 then C1 to show text “Incomplete”.
I hope this is a simple enough explanation. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use A1 B1 C1 cell,
C1 function is 
=IF(AND(A1="",B1=""),"Incomplete",IF(A1=B1,"complete","Partial"))

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A1&B1="","incomplete",IF(A1=B1,"complete","partial"))
```

in the other cell will do it

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that doesn't work is if cells A & B have numbers in them but they do not match. ie 3 & 2 it shows partial which is fine. But if the numbers match it still shows "partial". If they match I need C to show "complete". Hope this makes sense.

Comment: that makes sense, but I cannot duplicate it. When my numbers match, it does show "complete". Did the other answer work for you, or same issue?

Comment: same issue I'm afraid. Is there any way I can send/attach a test sheet for you to have a look at?

Comment: I put it up at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U45oCOTpMnwt3Fm4sPr9sf-nB1hMmm_dOu34snG4cR0/edit?usp=sharing for you to try

Comment: assuming you are not doing anything terribly excel specific, you can either go to sheets.google.com and create it there, turn link sharing on, let anyone on the web edit (yikes, but that is what I just did), and paste the link here. Or, you can try pasting your data into the sheet I linked here.

Comment: Didn't know that existed Jeremy. I'll give it a go later. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this in cell `C1`,

```
=IF(A1<>B1,"Partial",IF(A1="","InComplete","Complete"))
```